# MSDeploy throwing MissingMethodException on EventWriteVerbose when trying to deploy package to IIS

Tags: asp.net, jenkins, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I am using Jenkins to build and package an ASP.NET project. Everything works well up until I attempt to run the `<ProjectName>.deploy.cmd` file that is output with the packaging process

This error is output whether I run the `deploy.cmd` or run `msdeploy.exe` directly

The missing method, apparently, is `Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Tracing.WebDeployEventWriter.EventWriteVerbose(System.String, System.String, System.String)`

The full output is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'Void
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Tracing.WebDeployEventWriter.EventWriteVerbose(System.String,
>   System.String, System.String)'.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.TraceWrapper.EventWriteVerboseHelper(String
>   message, String user, String siteName)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.TraceWrapper.EventWriteVerbose(String
>   message, String user, String siteName)
>   at
>   MSDeploy.MSDeploy.Main(String[] unusedArgs)

The arguments being passed to `msdeploy.exe`:

> -source:package='C:\PROGRA~2\Jenkins\workspace\ProjectDirectory\Project.zip'
>   -dest:auto,computerName="localhost",userName="Administrator",password="apassword",includeAcls="False",tempAgent="UseTempAgent"
>   -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"C:\PROGRA~2\Jenkins\workspace\ProjectDirectory\Project.SetParameters.xml"
>   -whatif

However, changing any of the arguments will result in the same output

Answer (score 1):

Although not exactly a fix, I downgraded to `Web Deploy 3.0` and I do not see this error anymore and the project deploys successfully

Answer (score 0):

similar to @justin answer

downgrading to **Webdeploy 3.5  instead of webdeploy 4.0** worked for me when i was using **azuredevops**

Answer (score 0):

Like those above, for Windows 10 Enterprise, I had to downgrade to Web Deploy 3.5 to resolve this.
I had to keep a copy of the Web Deploy 3.5 msi so that I can install it again, because some other apps (could be VS Code or some other VS products?) keep re-installing Web Deploy 4.0 when they do some upgrade.

Web Deploy 4.0 obviously doesn't work on my Windows 10 Enterprise. Even when I run msdeploy.exe without any parameter, the same error message above happens, so it's hopeless trying to resolve it.

Comment: how can I downgrade to 3.6? I have same issue.

Comment: @TusharMaru I un-installed the current version from "Add or remove programs" then installed the new version. For Web Deploy 3.6 you can find it here https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=43717