# Azure DevOps - The process 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' failed with exit code 3762504530

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am doing on premise deploy with Azure DevOps and I got this error as below. I am deploying this on the windows 10 pro machine. Could any help on this would be great help. As I have tried to find some solution but could not find.

```
The process 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' failed with exit code 3762504530

Failed to deploy web package to IIS website.
Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Tracing.WebDeployEventWriter.EventWriteVerbose(System.String, System.String, System.String)'.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.TraceWrapper.EventWriteVerboseHelper(String message, String user, String siteName)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.TraceWrapper.EventWriteVerbose(String message, String user, String siteName)
   at MSDeploy.MSDeploy.Main(String[] unusedArgs)

"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='C:\azagent\A1\_work\r1\a\temp_web_package_6877648714396305.zip' -dest:auto -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='SD' -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
2020-04-14T13:22:28.4943595Z Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' failed with exit code 3762504530
```

I have put more details.

```
[command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='C:\azagent\A1\_work\r1\a\temp_web_package_3355247159673458.zip' -dest:auto -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='SD' -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule2020-04-15T07:42:01.8379357Z Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' failed with exit code 3762504530
```

2020-04-15T07:42:01.8380492Z     at ExecState._setResult (C:\azagent\A1_work_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.156.9\node_modules\azure-pipelines-task-lib\toolrunner.js:816:25)
2020-04-15T07:42:01.8381798Z     at ExecState.CheckComplete (C:\azagent\A1_work_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.156.9\node_modules\azure-pipelines-task-lib\toolrunner.js:799:18)
2020-04-15T07:42:01.8383760Z     at ChildProcess. (C:\azagent\A1_work_tasks\IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup_1b467810-6725-4b6d-accd-886174c09bba\0.156.9\node_modules\azure-pipelines-task-lib\toolrunner.js:721:19)
2020-04-15T07:42:01.8384653Z     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
2020-04-15T07:42:01.8385039Z     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
2020-04-15T07:42:01.8386129Z     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
2020-04-15T07:42:01.8386764Z     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)
2020-04-15T07:42:01.8387253Z Retrying to deploy the package.
2020-04-15T07:42:01.8395750Z [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='C:\azagent\A1_work\r1\a\temp_web_package_3355247159673458.zip' -dest:auto -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='SD' -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
2020-04-15T07:42:01.8906481Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to IIS website.
2020-04-15T07:42:01.8929403Z ##[error]
Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Tracing.WebDeployEventWriter.EventWriteVerbose(System.String, System.String, System.String)'.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.TraceWrapper.EventWriteVerboseHelper(String message, String user, String siteName)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.TraceWrapper.EventWriteVerbose(String message, String user, String siteName)
   at MSDeploy.MSDeploy.Main(String[] unusedArgs)

2020-04-15T07:42:01.8933306Z ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe' failed with exit code 3762504530
2020-04-15T07:42:01.9112353Z ##[section]Finishing: IIS Web App Deploy

Comment: Code, please ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey I edited post and added that. If you need more info then let me know.

Comment: @TusharMaru Are you able to deploy manually with `msdeploy` on your build agent machine? Which version of `msdeploy.exe` is installed on your agent machine? Please try with `Webdeploy 3.5` as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199036/msdeploy-throwing-missingmethodexception-on-eventwriteverbose-when-trying-to-dep) case suggests. If you could deploy manually, but couldn't deploy from Azure DevOps Server 2019, please share your build pipeline and entire build log.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Microsoft Web Deploy V3 version I have. I have edited the question and put some more log.

Comment: When I run this command manually then also get I same error. I already have the webdeploy 3.

Comment: If you run this command manually also get this error, then your issue is not related to Azure DevOps, you need to get help from msdeploy side to solve the issue locally first. After that, try to use Azure DevOps to do the deployment.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT can you help me on this? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not an msdeploy expert. Any issue with DevOps, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution we need to remove the webdeploy 4.0 and downgrade to webdeploy 3.6 and then its working well.

Comment: Thank you! This would have taken a long time to debug otherwise.